# No HKEY_USERS registry entries created for ApplicationPoolIdentityUsers in Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: asp.net, iis, registry, application-pool, windows-server-2012-r2

I've got an ASP.NET app that I'm developing on a Windows 8.1 machine and deploying to a Windows Server 2012R2 machine. This app starts a command line executable via a call to `Diagnostics.Process.Start()`. This command line executable writes some default entries in the registry under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER on first run for the respective user. These are later accessed via calls to `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey()`.

When running the web app under its respective ApplicationPoolIdentity user on the 8.1 box it works perfectly well, but on the WS2012 box it does not. Upon further investigation it appears that 8.1 is creating entries under `HKEY_USERS` for these IIS virtual accounts, whereas WS2012 is not. NetworkService, DefaultAppPool etc have entries in the registry, but the virtual accounts don't, so if I don't run the app pool under an existing user on the WS2012 box (NetworkService, for instance) it can't write/read the registry entries and so it can't pull the settings.

Why is this? How do I allow Windows Server 2012 to create registry entries for ApplicationPoolIdentity user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

There were two things I had to do to fix this:
1) In the Advanced Settings of the App Pool, I set the "Load User Profile" setting to True;
2) Browse the Website from IIS.